# Resizing a Raid 0 partition

Tags: partitioning, raid

I have a single partition on a Raid 0 array of 3 drives using my motherboard's raid support(DFI INFINITY 975X LGA 775 Intel 975X ATX).

Currently I have Win XP 32bit installed.  I would like to install Windows 7 64bit when it comes out on a second partition of the same Raid array.  So I will need to resize the existing partition, making it smaller, and then create a second partition.

Is this possible?  I know there are apps out there for resizing partitions, but I am not sure of their support of RAID.  There are some options provided by Intel's Matrix RAID software, but I'm pretty sure that making a RAID 0 array smaller is not one of the options it provides.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partitioning software knows nothing about your raid setup so whatever software you chose, it will work fine.

However if you want to resize the raid array and not the partition I think you need to do that using the bios/firmware or the tool they sent along with your motherboard.

Comment: I have since found that you need the RAID controller's driver to support any kind of management of the partitions on the array.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Par said that partition software will recognize the RAID as one partition.

It is able to resize the RAID with the software, however, do a backup in advance to aviod any data loss is the most important thing.

http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/resize-raid.htm